# How do I fix a 1/2 broken DNN path?

Tags: dotnetnuke, friendly-url, dotnetnuke-7

Somehow my DNN has a broken path a particular url serves pages, but doesn't work for delete or advanced options (delivers a 404 error)

The taburls table has no entries for this tab.

If I change the url through the tabs table then I'm able to delete the page without issue.

I tried accessing the page options via tabid, but the tabid gets converted to the friendly name and then 404s.

I tried turning off friendly urls in my web.config but I may have done it wrong since the entire site would not load (yellowscreen of death)

I'm wondering where DNN is storing this path that is breaking the advanced options of whatever page is at the path.

How do I fix this url so it displays page options and lets me delete pages?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is going to the Admin/Page Management screen, can you make the changes you need to via that interface? If so, after making the changes, are you able to access the page and all the features/options correctly?

If that doesn't work, check the TabPath column in the TABS table to see if there are any bad paths in there for specific pages that you are having problems with.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look Chris. I don't have it fixed yet. If I update the tabpath and tabname to be something else then everything works fine (but it doesn't have the url I want). Is the tabs table the only one involved in mapping urls?